# How to delete all registry keys

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry

I want to delete all registry records in Windows 8. I don't know returning a restore point will solve this problem. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This could cause your windows to completely not working after this. What are you trying to do? Cause permanent damage to windows?

Comment: @Darius I want to delete some .dll files. I tried several ways but Only way to delete these files is deleting registry files. I think these .dll files are some kind of virus.

Comment: Your best bet would be to run a cleaner utility like ccleaner, maybe malwarebytes or other scanner and virus scanner. Don't mess around deleting .dll files and registry keys.

Comment: @Raystafarian I am using Bitdefender total security and Ccleaner. neither of them deleting these .dll files for example C:\Users\hellzone\pokerzone.dll, C:\Users\hellzone\betpoker.dll. I removed all programs with "Programs and Features".

Comment: If you know the particular filename, try doing a search for that particular filename on the registry, and delete ALL registry entries that matches the search. Or try doing it under Safe Mode. To trigger safe mode from inside Windows 8 -> Start+R (run) -> msconfig -> Boot tab -> "Safe Boot" - Minimal. And see if you can delete those DLL from your system.

Comment: @Darius I deleted all registery entries matching with these dll file names and still same. I couldn't delete these dll files in Safe mode.Format is only remaining way I think.I don't want to format my pc for 1-2 dll files.

Comment: deleting the registry entries won't change your ability to delete these dll files.  Unlocker might help in a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried with unlocker(http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and It gives error "The object could not be deleted.". I also tried "Take ownership" program it says "access denied" very funny :D

Comment: Alright so `regedit` find those entries you want to delete and hit the delete key

Comment: You don't really sound like you should be mucking around with the registry. I don't think that randomly deleting stuff because you 'think' they're a virus is going to improve matters.

Comment: If this is only affecting one user (hellzone) how about creating a new user, and copying your files from hellzone user profile to the new one. And see if you can delete the old username which in turn should also wipe that .dll which may be running / invoked while you are logged in as hellzone.

Answer (score 0):

First use the free version of MalwareBytes if that fails then proceed below.

```
 Get norton antivirus
 login mynortonaccount.com
 download the emergency bootable ISO
 burn it to CD or make a bootable USB drive
 write down you serial number.

Boot your system from CD or USB
enter your serial number
use the tools here to scan and clean your system.
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Windows DVD or USB

```
Select repair 
select command prompt
```

try deleting the files.

Comment: Why did you post two answers? Why not combine it all into one?

Comment: @Raystafarian  The answers are completely different.  If my answer is voted up or selected then others viewing the question will know which was the answer instead of having to try 2 different things.